# Look up id value to pass to controller on save of new record via standard controller

Tags: apex, controller-extension

Can anyone help me with the test class for below controller. I am trying to get the values of the vf page on save of a new record. standard controller will be null at that point but i need to access the values so I can save it.

```
public CA_SamsAccountController(ApexPages.StandardController std) {
  samsid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
   accid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('AccountId');
   if(samsid!=null)
    cont =  (CA_SamsAccount__c)std.getRecord();  --- this line gives me error whenever I try to run the test class if i remove the above if condition
    }

    public PageReference save() { 
        string acctype = bc.getSamsAccountTypes();
        cont.CA_Sams_Account_Name__c = str;
        cont.CA_Account__c = acc.id;
        cont.CA_Account_name__c = accname;
        cont.CA_ApiLastName__c = '.api';
        cont.CA_Country__c = selectedCountry;
        cont.CA_contract__c = contractid;
        cont.CA_Parent_ID__c = selectedParent;
        cont.CA_MisPassword__c = temp1;
        cont.CA_ApiPassword__c = temp;
        cont.CA_AccountTypeId__c = acctype;
        con = [select lastname,firstname,phone,email from contact where id=: cont.CA_Contact__c limit 1];   --- I always have cont as null and hence not able to fetch contact
        cont.CA_First_Name__c = con.firstname;
        cont.CA_Last_Name__c = con.lastname;
        cont.CA_Telephone__c = con.phone;
        cont.CA_Email__c = con.email;
        insert cont;
    }

     public string getApiorgname()
{
   string apiorgname = '';
   string api = cont.CA_Sams_Account_Name__c;  --- same issues goes here as well
   list<CA_SamsAccount__c> clist = [select CA_ApiFirstName__c from CA_SamsAccount__c where CA_ApiFirstName__c=: api];
   if(clist.size()>0)
       for(CA_SamsAccount__c c : clist)
            uniquename.add(c.CA_ApiFirstName__c);
   apiorgname = checkpattern(api);
   apiorgname = apiorgname + '.api';
   system.debug('api==='+ apiorgname);
   return apiorgname;
}
```

## Test class

```
static testmethod void mytest(){
        Account a = new account(name = 'test');
        insert a;
        contact c = new contact (lastname='abc', firstname = 'ABC', phone ='987656');
        insert c;
         System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('AccountId', a.id);
         //get your page reference here. PageReference pageRef = Page.YourPageName;
        //pageRef.getParameters().put('Id', null );

       //pageRef.getParameters().put('AccountId', a.id);
        CA_SamsAccountController cs = new CA_SamsAccountController(null);
        cs.save();
        cs.ContactPopulated();
       list<SelectOption> testoptions = cs.getParent();
        list<SelectOption> testoptions1 = cs.getCountry();
        cs.selectedCountry = 'none';
        cs.selectedParent = 'none';
    }
     static testmethod void mytest1(){
        Account a = new account(name = 'test');
        insert a;
         string samsacc = a.name.replace(' ','_').tolowercase();
        contact c = new contact (lastname='abc', firstname = 'ABC', phone ='987656');
        insert c;
        CA_SamsAccount__c sacc= new CA_SamsAccount__c(CA_Account__c = a.id, CA_Contact__c = c.id, CA_Country__c = 'test', CA_Parent_ID__c = 'test', CA_Sams_Account_Name__c = samsacc );
        insert sacc;
        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('id', sacc.id);
         System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('AccountId', a.id);

        apexPages.standardController newCntr=new apexPages.standardController(sacc);
        CA_SamsAccountController cs = new CA_SamsAccountController(newCntr);
        cs.save();
        cs.ContactPopulated();
       list<SelectOption> testoptions = cs.getParent();
        list<SelectOption> testoptions1 = cs.getCountry();
        cs.selectedCountry = 'none';
        cs.selectedParent = 'none';
         cs.con = c;
         cs.getApiorgname();
         cs.getAPIpassword();
```

Answer (score 1):

1.)You need to get the page reference for the page first as below:

`PageReference pageRef = Page.YourPageName;`

2.)  Set the current page in test class first as below :

`Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);`

3.)Then set the parameters as below :

```
pageRef.getParameters().put('Id', samsid );

pageRef.getParameters().put('AccountId', accid );
```

4.)Then instantiate standard controller and its extension:

```
ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController (obj);    
CA_SamsAccountController caSams = new CA_SamsAccountController (sc);
```

Comment: @Priya It would be better if you could post your test class.As community will get a better idea of your problem.

Comment: Yes Rohit, sure.

Comment: @Priya, Set page reference first and then set its parameters. In your test class , you haven't set the page reference and hence it is unable to find the parameters . Just follow the mentioned steps in my answer and see if it works.

Comment: @Priyakrishnamurthy , edited your answer

Comment: I tried the same code.. no luck still it has null value. not sure where am i missing it.

Comment: @Priyakrishnamurthy , replace " pageRef.getParameters().put('Id', sacc.id );" with " pageRef.getParameters().put('id', sacc.id );" and try

Comment: Ya I changed and tried running it again.. Its still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below piece of code where is shows how to test the Standard Controller extension and how to setCurrentPage reference and add url parameter.

```
Contact cObj = new Contact(LastName='TestContact#123')
insert cObj;
ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(cObj);
NewContactCntrl testAccPlan = new NewContactCntrl(sc);

PageReference pageRef = Page.ContactPage;    //set the Page 
pageRef.getParameters().put('id', String.valueOf(cObj.Id)); //Add URL parameter
Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried this but still it has null value. I have posted my test class as well